# Error when compiling: "Illegal sequential statement"

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

sorry if my problem seems evident, I am new at VHDL
I tried to write a parity generator which count the number of 1 in a Vector(d) and assign a true or false to the variable odds and even.

my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
--------------------------------------------------
ENTITY testing IS
  GENERIC (N : positive := 4);
  PORT (d   : IN bit_vector(N-1 DOWNTO 0);
        odd : OUT bit;
        even : OUT bit);
END testing;
--------------------------------------------------
architecture verhalten of testing is

begin 
    process(d)


        function anzahl_1(d_s : in std_logic_vector) return natural is
            variable nb : natural;
            begin 
                nb :=0;
                lbl: for i in N-1 DOWNTO 0 generate
---d_S(i) <= d_S(i+1) XOR d(i);
                    if d_s(i) = '1' then 
                        nb := nb +1 ;
                    end if;
                end generate lbl;
            return nb;
        end anzahl_1;
    begin   

        if (anzahl_1(d) REM 2) = 0 then 
            odd <= '0';
            even <='1';
        else 
            odd <= '1';
            even <='0';
        end if;
    end process;

end verhalten;
```

I get the following errors but I dont know where to start, could you guys please help me out?

The errors:

```
GPG.vhd(21): Illegal sequential statement.
GPG.vhd(31): No feasible entries for subprogram "anzahl_1".
Bad expression in left operand of infix expression "=".
GPG.vhd(31): Type error resolving infix expression "=" as type std.STANDARD.BOOLEAN.
```

Comment: To get your code to analyze replace both instances of the  reserved word `generate` with the reserved word `loop` and the type mark of the subtype indication for `d_s` `std_logic_vector` in the function specification with `bit_vector` (`function anzahl_1(d_s : in bit_vector) return natural is`).

Comment: A generate statement is a concurrent statement controlling conditional elaboration, you want a loop statement (the first error). The change to bit_vector fixes the remaining.  The second is because you call anzahl_1 with a parameter mismatch. The third and fourth because the subprogram is not identified and not overloaded. Parity can be done without counting bits (popcount).

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked as you said!